# Помогите решить задачу. Нужно перевернуть строки на си. Код будет ниже

Tags: c

Пожалуйста, помогите решить задачу.
Напишите программу rev, имеющую один аргумент – имя файла, которая выводит содержимое файла, в котором каждую строку переворачивает наоборот (располагает символы в обратном порядке).
Пример вызова: ./rev test.txt

Comment: `код будет ниже` - это в смысле когда мы его сделаем и выложим? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

алгоритм простой:

1. в цикле `pos` идёте от 0 элемента до `N / 2`
2. `N`, т.е. длину строки можно получить через функцию `strlen()`
3. меняете символы местами удалённым слева направо и справа налево на расстояние `pos` от начала и конца строки соответственно с использованием промежуточного хранилища

   ```
    tmp = a;
    a = b;
    b = tmp;
   ```

надеюсь этого достаточно, чтобы вы реализовали код?